# Display "no post" message

Tags: posts, shortcode

I am working from someone else's shortcode and not sure what I'm looking at. I need to add a custom message if no posts meet the criteria.

[su_posts template="templates/default-loop.php" post_type="rsd_event" taxonomy="event_type" tax_term="5709" order="desc"]

Comment: You'll need to find the actual code that this shortcode refers to. Without seeing the actual code we can't help you fix this.

I'd start looking in `functions.php`, but it may be in a custom functions file as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.